# Text alignment in spinner item

Tags: android, spinner

How to move the text near to the line? like the [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iDqYI.png)

Comment: Can you add some code?
android:padding="0dp" maybe helps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is very simple, just create a **xml** file named as **spinner_item.xml** with content as

```
<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:textColor="#111111"
android:padding="10dp"
android:textAlignment="center"
/>
```

Now in your java class, instead of adding android's default view resource add your custom view resource as

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, R.layout.spinner_item, myList);
adapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.spinner_item);
```

Comment: it works for me

ArrayAdapter adapter2 = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this, R.array.planets_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);